# How to save inside of the cell at nested parfool loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to save the error inside of the nested parfor loop inside of the cell, but unfortunately I was not successful. All part of the code works fine except  this part:  `err_list{l1}(l2)={mean(tmp) [lambda1_list(l1),lambda2_list(l2)]};`

Would someone help me to fix this?

```
err_list = cell(length(lambda1_list),length(lambda2_list));

     parfor l1 = 1:length(lambda1_list) % over l1
                this_param = params;


            % Create this to save CV error:
            tmp=zeros(params.nfolds,1);

        for l2 = 1:length(lambda2_list)



            this_param.lambda1 = lambda1_list(l1);
            this_param.lambda2 = lambda2_list(l2);
            % Get Nth fold training and test data and compute CV error
            for Fold=1:size(Fold_indices,2)

            Y_train=y_train(logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);
            Y_test=y_train(~logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);

            N=size(Y_test,1);
            Dictionary_train=dictionary_train(logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);

           Dictionary_test=dictionary_train(~logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);


            [totBeta,theta,omega,rho,nu] = learn(Dictionary_train,Y_train, this_param);


           err = (1/N) * sum(sum(( Y_test- Dictionary_test * totBeta).^2));


           tmp(Fold,1)=err;
         end

            err_list{l1}(l2)={mean(tmp) [lambda1_list(l1),lambda2_list(l2)]};



        end

    end %

The error I get is :
***Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.***
and it's belong t
```

o this part of code:

```
 err_list{l1}(l2)={mean(tmp) [lambda1_list(l1),lambda2_list(l2)]};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code

```
err_list = cell(1,length(lambda1_list));

     parfor l1 = 1:length(lambda1_list) % over l1
                this_param = params;
           this_l1=l1;

            % Create this to save CV error:
            tmp=zeros(params.nfolds,1);
        err_list_temp = cell(1,length(lambda2_list));
        for l2 = 1:length(lambda2_list)



            this_param.lambda1 = lambda1_list(l1);
            this_param.lambda2 = lambda2_list(l2);
            % Get Nth fold training and test data and compute CV error
            for Fold=1:size(Fold_indices,2)

            Y_train=y_train(logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);
            Y_test=y_train(~logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);

            N=size(Y_test,1);
            Dictionary_train=dictionary_train(logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);

           Dictionary_test=dictionary_train(~logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);


            [totBeta,theta,omega,rho,nu] = learn(Dictionary_train,Y_train, this_param);


           err = (1/N) * sum(sum(( Y_test- Dictionary_test * totBeta).^2));


           tmp(Fold,1)=err;
            end
         tmpMean=mean(tmp);

            err_list_temp{l2}={tmpMean [lambda1_list(this_l1),lambda2_list(l2)]};

        end
        err_list{l1}=err_list_temp;
    end %
```

Answer (score 0):

2D cells are indexed `err_list{l1,l2}` not `err_list{l1}(l2)`, which would index what you want but is not allowed inside a parfor loop. To work around you have to get the slice which belongs to each index of the parfor loop, work with it and write it back.

```
err_list = cell(length(lambda1_list),length(lambda2_list));

parfor l1 = 1:length(lambda1_list) % over l1
    slice_err_list=err_list(l1,:);
    %irrelevant code removed 
    for l2 = 1:length(lambda2_list)
        %irrelevant code removed
        slice_err_list{l2}={[lambda1_list(l1),lambda2_list(l2)]};
    end
    err_list(l1,:)=slice_err_list;
end %
```

Comment: This doesn't work inside of parfor loop, but inside of for loop